# MVC4 - My Custom Route isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

So I have a custom route in my MVC4 web app below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SecondarySportsCategoryLanding",
            url: "sports/{name}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "FrontCategoriesController", action = "Sports", name = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I have that placed above my default one as well.  What's happening is when I go to /sports I get this error:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /sports

I have the controller specified, and inside that I have an Action titled Sports with 2 optional parameters (defaulted to nulls).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`controller = "FrontCategoriesController"` should be `controller = "FrontCategories"`

Because the framework automatically inserts `Controller` into the value for you.